# Spring DaoSupport and @PersistanceContext EntityManager?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, persistence, dao

One of the most difficult things about understand Spring is that Spring supports multiple approaches to the same problem.

So in my application I using injected EntityManager using the @PersistanceContext annotation, for example:

```
@Repository
public class JpaDao extends JpaDaoSupport implements Dao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "PersistanceUnit", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;
```

**Is this approach compatible with extending JpaDaoSupport** (which requires injecting in an EntityManager)? To me it looks like two incompatible approaches to the solving the same problem, but I would like some advice from someone who has more experience with Spring.

If I shouldn't be extending JpaDaoSupport, how should I build my DAO using the @PersistenceContext approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct that they are two different approaches to the same problem. Which one is "better" is a matter of taste, I think. Using annotations has the benefit of avoiding Spring import dependencies in your code, and even the Spring JavaDoc for **JpaDaoSupport** suggests using them for new JPA projects. **JpaDaoSupport** is there to make Spring's support for JPA equivalent to its support for other ORM strategies (**HibernateDaoSupport**, **JdbcDaoSupport**, **TopLinkDaoSupport**, etc.). In those cases, annotation-based injection isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

For injecting the EntityManager you just need to add the next definition

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

you can get more information about this topic in [this post](http://blog.springsource.com/2006/08/07/using-jpa-in-spring-without-referencing-spring/) from the oficial blog

Comment: I understand how inject the EntityManager, I have that working fine. My issue is more about best practices for Spring DAO.

Comment: I think that if you use JPA as an standard approach, forcing you to a Spring solution (i.e. extending JpaSupport) is a no sense. If you keep tied to JPA+EJB3 injection you can migrate your jars to an Application Server whenever you want.
My 2 micro cents :)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather recommend you not to extend JpaDaoSupport, spring will do everything for you. Follow the link suggested by diega for more information, same blog I have followed to upgrade my application to support spring - jpa.